# How to override some CSS class settings

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 5.1 and as a Java programmer I have a lot of difficult to handle CSS classes. For instance, I want to override some of CSS properties removing the round corners of a DIV, wich renderized is:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: auto; width: auto; z-index: 0; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; display: block; visibility: visible; height: 16px;" id="j_idt28" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-south footer ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-south">
    <div style="position: relative; visibility: visible; height: 15px;" class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content">
    <span style="color:#000000;background-color:#FFFF00;font-size:small;">This is a text inside a div!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the upper DIV uses a lot of CSS classes, including my class called **footer** which is declared in my CSS as:

```css
.footer .ui-layout-unit-content {
 background-color: #FFFF00 !important;
 padding: 0px !important;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I could paint the background as yellow, but other properties cannot be overwriten. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emmanuel's help, the solution was simple: there is another class setting CSS atrributes for rounded DIV, so I overrided it:

```
.footer.ui-layout-pane .ui-layout-unit-content.ui-widget-content {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    padding: 0px;
}

.footer.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

.footer.ui-widget-content {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to override a rule that is previously defined you have to increase **specificity**.

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.
>
> **How is it calculated?**
>
> The specificity is calculated on the
>   concatenation of the count of each selectors type. It is not a weight
>   that is applied to the corresponding matching expression.
>
> In case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the
>   CSS is applied to the element.

So your rule could be written as:

```
.footer.ui-layout-pane .ui-layout-unit-content.ui-widget-content {
    background-color: #FFFF00 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks emmanuel. I finally found another class which was setting another parameters for the rounded div and solved it creating another entry in CSS as in my last answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use your element inspector to find which of these classes is applying the style then override it using 
`!important` rule. For example: `border-radius: 0px !important;`

Comment: I was already using "!important", but there was another class overriding "border-radius" with "border-bottom-left-radius", "border-bottom-right-radius", "border-top-left-radius" and "border-top-right-radius".